# In Solr Dashboard how to auto increase the height of tagcloud panel when the height of terms panel increases due to legend addition?

Tags: solr, lucidworks, banana

I have two panels "The term panel as a bar chart" and "The tagcloud panel" in a single row inside banana dashboard.If a "legend" is added to the top or the bottom of the bar chart the height of the entire row increases to the height of the terms panel. But the height of the tagcloud panel remains to its same size.
I want the height of the tagcloud panel also to auto increase to the height of the row.
Inside the method `$scope.close_edit` of the panels/terms I added `$scope.$broadcast('render');` but that doesn't help me to resize the neighbouring panel to the increased row height after adding the legend to the terms panel.

Any help on how to fix this issue would be great, thanks!

[image: panel height resize issue in banana]